# TFS 2017 Build Templates Property needs attention

Tags: tfs

I'm currently trying to create default build templates on Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2017.

I created a template via the REST API and it's going well overall.

But... One Question.

If anybody creates a build with my template, I wanna show him which settings he **have to set up** to run the build well. Until now I've done this:

[image: Choose Project for Packing]
The JSON looks like this:

```
...,
    {
        "enabled": true,
        "continueOnError": false,
        "alwaysRun": false,
        "displayName": "NuGet Packager ",
        "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
        "task": {
            "id": "333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f24b",
            "versionSpec": "0.*",
            "definitionType": "task"
        },
        "inputs": {
            "searchPattern": "<chooseProject>",
            "outputdir": "",
            "includeReferencedProjects": "false",
            "versionByBuild": "false",
            "versionEnvVar": "",
            "requestedMajorVersion": "1",
            "requestedMinorVersion": "0",
            "requestedPatchVersion": "0",
            "configurationToPack": "$(BuildConfiguration)",
            "buildProperties": "",
            "nuGetAdditionalArgs": "",
            "nuGetPath": ""
        }
    }...
```

How can I change the json to make it look like this?
[image: Needs attention]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need  to add a `"required": true,` in the **inputs**.

You could also refer the source code of this task in github--[PublishBuildArtifacts](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/PublishBuildArtifacts/task.json)

Comment: Found it. you need a parameter to do this, after that i'ts all copy paste. Thanks a lot!